# Ubuntu 14.04 Try to "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa" failed

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-14.04, tweak

I try to add ppa for install Ubuntu Tweak, but I can't do this. Terminal print:
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:tualatrix/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
Then how install Ubuntu Tweak?

Answer (score 1):

I turned off SpIDer Guard and SpIDer Gate and add repository. It's worked! Because the PPA I mentioned ("The official Ubuntu Tweak stable repository") is alive and provide packages for 14.04 LTS https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty.